# Exclude classes of jar files from jacoco coverage report

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

Jacoco code coverage report is also including classes from "system path jar" that I have added using below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/axis-1.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to exclude the files of this jar from jacoco plugin like this :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/org/apache/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/org/globus/**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                                runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But the exclusion is not working. It is still showing the coverage report for the files contained in jar.
As it is shown in image, the files in **org.apacke.** and **org.clobus.** package should not be there in the coverage report.

[image]

Comment: I think the exclude pattern only supports some variations of wildcards. E.g. either from the front: */**Test* or at the end: org/apache/* - I think your pattern should only be "org/apache/**/*". Another way would be to work with includes and only include your own packages, since that will probably be a much shorter list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer of it

```
 <exclude>**/lib/*</exclude>
```

The above exclusion exclude the classes from my jar file with `system` scope.

Comment: It seems that system scope's file structure is based on how it is put in the maven build, not how it is exploded as package dirs.

Comment: How to exclude a jar from Jacoco JavaAgent or it can only takes classes(need to extract jar?) ?