# How to exclude and include properly classes, packages and jar classes, lib from the jacoco report (Instrumentation offline)

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using JaCoCo code coverage, but the report is including classes from jar, lib. (Offline Instrumentation, Maven)

I solved the problem with the offline configuration since "aspectj-maven-plugin" was changing the class files, and also now I successfully exclude the packages outside of `target/classes` -> `src`. thanks to this answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189496/jacoco-offline-instrumentation-in-goalinstrument-goal-analyzes-the-entire?noredirect=1#comment102758935_58189496).
But now I am getting the classes from jar, lib inside the report and I have not idea how to exclude then. I Show my configuration and examples below

I also tried this solution [Exclude classes of jar files from jacoco coverage report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727952/exclude-classes-of-jar-files-from-jacoco-coverage-report) But it doesn't work for me.
`<exclude>**/lib/*</exclude>`

My jacoco offline configuration:

```
<properties>
  <jacoco.version>0.8.4</jacoco.version>
  <argLine></argLine>
</properties>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
  <classifier>runtime</classifier>
  <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
</dependency>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- this configuration affects all goals -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/company/rrPackage/**/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>org/**/*.class</exclude>                                               
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

surefire-plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testNGArtifactName>...</testNGArtifactName>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>...</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skip>${skip.test}</skip>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>                       
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <properties>
                        ... 
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And the reason what I think that I am getting classes from jar inside de jacoco:report. In my pom.xml I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I have a couple of import in my classes like this

```
import org.hsqldb.lib.StringUtil;
```

for example:
This has no dependency on the pom.xml but is used in one of the project classes, and jacoco shows it in the report

```
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
```

I have other cases with the same behavior that result in the same problem: Jacoco show those classes from jar in the report, as shown in the images

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `includes` instead of `excludes`. Notice that you need .class at the end.
try something like that:

```
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>com/company/package/**/*.class</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

Base on your example:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- this configuration affects all goals -->
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/company/packageToInclude/**/*.class</include>                                               
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you! That definitely solved my problem. I was trying something like that before but without `.class` at the end.

Comment: I was too focus on finding the solution on how to `exclude` these classes under the `lib` folder and I have never thought about this solution. This solved my problem indeed!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you generate `lib` directory, because you don't provide [**complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

However in case of the following example

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```
class Example {
}
```

`src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

and `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.4</jacoco.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
      <classifier>runtime</classifier>
      <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeArtifactIds>junit</includeArtifactIds>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>instrument</goal>
              <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

execution of `mvn clean verify` produces

```
$ ls -R target/classes
target/classes:
Example.class  lib

target/classes/lib:
junit-4.12.jar
```

and following report

[image: report before exclusions]

And after addition of following `<configuration>`

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>instrument</goal>
              <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>lib/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

execution of the same command `mvn clean verify` produces following report

[image: report after exclusions]

If the above doesn't help, then please provide **absolutely complete** example allowing everybody else to reproduce exactly the same what you do.